# Turnover share attributable to AFOLs

Tags: lego-group, afol

Traditionally LEGO has been known as a kid's toy, but there is a growing community of AFOLs (Adult Fans Of LEGO).

**How big share of LEGO's turnover is attributable to AFOLs?**

Comment: Turnover can mean quite a few things; do you mean how long a person is actively buying LEGO bricks?

Comment: @Mark Stewart: Revenue, money on the income statement.

Comment: OK, pure accounting definition, not inventory.  I would look at the financial statements but since it is a private company, that would not be available.  I would then be forced to look at shelf space at stores to see how much space is dedicated to young age groups vs. older, and pure building sets (non-themed)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information is controlled by The LEGO Group and not something we have access to.